# Reading a textfile and calling a class with each text file line

Tags: c#, performance

How could I get a better performance in my C# application? Or what should I change in my source code?

I would appreciate any kind of help.

This code is reading each line of a textfile which stores values like var1:var2 and calls a class with those values.

Function which calls the class:

```
private void bunifuFlatButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var streamReader = File.OpenText(filePath))
    {
        var lines = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split(new char[] { '\n' });
        var count = lines.Count();

        bunifuProgressBar1.MaximumValue = count;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            string[] words = lines[i].Split(':');
            string hash = mega.GenerateHash(words[0].ToLowerInvariant(), mega.PrepareKey(words[1].ToBytes()));

            bunifuCustomLabel4.Text = "Working: Total: " + count + ". Currently: " + (i + 1) + ".";
            bunifuCustomLabel4.Update();
            bunifuProgressBar1.Value = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

The class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MegaTool
{
    public static class mega
    {

        private static readonly Rijndael RijndaelCbc;
        private static readonly byte[] DefaultIv = new byte[16];

        static mega()
        {
            RijndaelCbc = Rijndael.Create();
            RijndaelCbc.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
            RijndaelCbc.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        }

        public static byte[] ToBytes(this string data)
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        }

        public static byte[] PrepareKey(byte[] data)
        {
            byte[] pkey = new byte[] { 0x93, 0xC4, 0x67, 0xE3, 0x7D, 0xB0, 0xC7, 0xA4, 0xD1, 0xBE, 0x3F, 0x81, 0x01, 0x52, 0xCB, 0x56 };

            for (int it = 0; it < 65536; it++)
            {
                for (int idx = 0; idx < data.Length; idx += 16)
                {
                    byte[] key = data.CopySubArray(16, idx);

                    pkey = EncryptAes(pkey, key);
                }
            }

            return pkey;
        }

        public static byte[] EncryptAes(byte[] data, byte[] key)
        {
            using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = RijndaelCbc.CreateEncryptor(key, DefaultIv))
            {
                return encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }

        public static T[] CopySubArray<T>(this T[] source, int length, int offset = 0)
        {
            T[] result = new T[length];
            while (--length >= 0)
            {
                if (source.Length > offset + length)
                {
                    result[length] = source[offset + length];
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        public static string GenerateHash(string email, byte[] passwordAesKey)
        {
            byte[] emailBytes = email.ToBytes();
            byte[] hash = new byte[16];

            for (int i = 0; i < emailBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                hash[i % 16] ^= emailBytes[i];
            }

            for (int it = 0; it < 16384; it++)
            {
                hash = EncryptAes(hash, passwordAesKey);
            }

            byte[] result = new byte[8];
            Array.Copy(hash, 0, result, 0, 4);
            Array.Copy(hash, 8, result, 4, 4);

            return result.ToBase64();
        }

        public static string ToBase64(this byte[] data)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(Convert.ToBase64String(data));
            sb.Replace('+', '-');
            sb.Replace('/', '_');
            sb.Replace("=", string.Empty);

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your title is too generic to be useful. Please retitle the question to state what the code does, as per the [ask] guidelines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> public static T[] CopySubArray<T>(this T[] source, int length, int offset = 0)
> {
>     T[] result = new T[length];
>     while (--length >= 0)
>     {
>         if (source.Length > offset + length)
>         {
>             result[length] = source[offset + length];
>         }
>     }
>
>     return result;
> }
> ```

I wonder why did you write this method? You can replace it with [`Array.Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft(v=vs.110).aspx) that, strangely enough, you already use in another place and even the exact same overload:

> ```
> Array.Copy(hash, 0, result, 0, 4);
> ```

Signature:

```
public static void Copy(
    Array sourceArray,
    int sourceIndex,
    Array destinationArray,
    int destinationIndex,
    int length
)
```

---

> ```
> public static string GenerateHash(string email, byte[] passwordAesKey)
> ```

This method should only generate a hash and not an encoded string. Encoding the hash is a responsibility for a different method.

---

> ```
> ToBase64
> ```

Likewise is this method doing too much. It not only creates a base64 string but also replaces some characters. This should moved to a new method like `CleanUpBase64String` or whatever it does. It can be `private` but this kind of custom processing should be encapsulated.

---

Basically this is how it should look like:

```
public static byte[] GenerateHash(string email, byte[] passwordAesKey)
{
    ..
}

public static string GenerateHashBase64String(string email, byte[] passwordAesKey)
{
    var hash = GenerateHash(email, passwordAesKey);
    return ToEncodedBase64(hash);
}

public static string ToEncodedBase64(this byte[] data)
{
    var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(data)
    return CleanUpBase64String(base64String);
}

private static string CleanUpBase64String(string value)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No purpose to reading all lines into memory

```
    string line;
    while((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)  
    {
        string[] words = line.Split(':');
```

Update text on every line is a lot of unnecessary over head
Same for progress bar

Comment: Thank you for your response, been using the for loop cause the ProgressBar needed values to work with.

Comment: You did ask how to get better performance

Answer (score 1):

This might also be a case for parallelization. Generating hash seems to be pretty isolated operation. I would test [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx) ([here is an example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx), in your case parallelization would be done for lines instead of files).

However: 
This will required changes to bunifuCustomLabel4 text update and bunifuProgressBar1 update par. If your problem is that GUI hangs for the duration of calculations (I would guess so, but hard to say from code sample) you need to handle updating progress bar and text from a different thread anyway.